# Best way to anonymise nginx logs

Tags: nginx, logging

I'm looking for a way to anonymise nginx logs (both, error and access logs) and it should have the following properties:

- no way to find out the IP Address of a user
- there should be a way to know how many different users the site has

Geolocation Tracking would be nice but is not a must-have.

My first idea was to create a hash of the IP address, but given that most IPs are IP4 there are roughly 4 Billion options which is reversable very easily.

Are there existing solutions or strategies and how would I implement them?

Answer (score 1):

Here they map the IP address to a shortened version:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477239/anonymize-ip-logging-in-nginx

I would personally use Google Analytics with anonimized IPs to do all the counting, tracking etc. and then just remove the IP form your logs altogether.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ip-anonymization

```
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
```

Comment: I'm working on a sensible product (a cryptocurrency wallet) and I don't think people would be comfortable with google analytics on the site. How anonymous is a shortened IP?

Comment: Depends how much you shorten it by. If your application is sensitive, then security must also be a strong consideration. If you forsake all IP logging in favour of anonymity, you also forsake the features of many great security tools which could help in protecting you. It's a bit of a catch-22. Of course, any truly concerned visitor should access your application via VPN, something you could actually offer as part of the experience.

Answer (score 1):

The module [ipscrub](http://ipscrub.org) lets you log IP addresses hashed with an ephemeral salt.

It won't help with your second requirement of counting distinct users though, because the hash changes every so often, so if you count distinct hashes you will overcount.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own log format http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format with a custom
variable instead of $remote_addr which can be almost anything.